# Как получить содержимое заголовка H1 текущей страницы?

Tags: php

**PHP**
Требуется получить содержимое заголовка `<h1>`  текущей страницы для дальнейшего вывода в хлебных крошках (breadcrumbs).

В данный момент в крошках выводится название файла (`page-name.php`). То есть вид крошек примерно следующий:
"Главная > page-name.php", 
а хотелось бы иметь 
"Главная > Название страницы" (которое берется из содержимого заголовка `h1` этой страницы)

Javascript, конечно, хорошо, но он не индексируется поисковиками

Код крошек:

```
<?php

function breadcrumbs($text = '', $sep = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Главная')
{
    $bc = '<div id="crumbs">' . $text;    
    $site = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];    
    $crumbs = array_filter(explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));    
    $bc .= '<span><a href="' . $site . '">' . $home . '</a>' . $sep . '</span>';    
    $nm = count($crumbs);
    $i  = 1;

    foreach ($crumbs as $crumb) {
        $link = ucfirst(str_replace(array(
            ".php",
            "-",
            "_"
        ), array(
            "",
            " ",
            " "
        ), $crumb));

        $sep = $i == $nm ? '' : $sep;        
        $site .= '/' . $crumb;        
        $bc .= '<span><a href="' . $site . '" >' . $link . '</a>' . $sep . '</span>';
        $i++;
    }
    $bc .= '</div>';

    return $bc;    
}

?>

<?= breadcrumbs() ?>
```

Comment: С помощью Javascript можно получить содержимое любого тега, в том числе и H1

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. чем получить? пхп? тогда сначала почитайте что такое пхп и как оно работает.

Comment: Контент не генерится - статичные страницы

Comment: А крошки как вставляются? Ajax? Или статичные страницы - php?

Comment: Вставляются через include

Answer (score 1):

1. парсить - что есть очень нехорошо
2. вытаскивать контент из бд (или как
           он там генерится) и передавать его
           объекту DOMDocument, из которого
           потом вытаскивать как значение ноды заголовка - решение более похожее на верное

PS для исключения ошибки, как парсинга так и передачи строки в объект DOMDocument, посоветовал бы отфильтровать строку контента с помощью [tidy::cleanRepair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) (требуется поддержка сервером)